# Installation ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: 12.04

How shall i follow the installation process i had tried by my USB Pendrive but was not success ful even i tried to install by making my USB a bootable even then it was not proceeded .... later tried a software called Multi Bootable USB Creator used to install many OS in the form of .iso file but even this doesn.t work i have downloaded 64bit ubuntu 12.04 LTS .. Kindly suggest need someones help .. .

Thanking you !

Comment: Create a bootable ubuntu usb drive through unetbootin software.

Answer (score 0):

you can try install ubuntu with unetbootin (make usb bootable) easily. you just run it after download without any installing and make your usb bootable with ubuntu .iso file.
then reboot your system and install it.